# How to make SCSI enclosure LEDs blink?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, supermicro, scsi

I have a SCSI enclosure (supermicro BPN-SAS-825TQ) residing on Ubuntu 16.04.

Is there an `sg_ses` (or `sg_senddiag` or other) command I can send to the enclosure, that will make the Rear LEDs blink, even if there's no disk in the enclosure?

Answer (score 2):

After having spent an hour trying to figure out how to get the correct indices for `sg_ses` command to work, I ended up using `encled` utility from this project https://github.com/amarao/sdled which has much more intuitive interface. It's a python script, so no compilation required, you can just download it and use right away.

> Encled - utility to change location / fault LED for enclosure.

"location" and "fault" is just how LEDs are named. They both may actually be represented by a single LED, but `locate` would make it blink, while `fault` would just turn it on continuously.

Note: the project has both `sdled` and `encled` utilities — you want the latter.

Examples:

- List devices and LED status on them: `./encled`
- Turn on "locate" LED on /dev/sdbe device: `./encled sdbe locate`
- Turn off all LEDs on all devices: `./encled all off`

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your particular backplane being visible to the host system (it should be visible as SCSCI device under `lsscsi -g`). In general, to turn on ID LED in a slot 1 of the /dev/sg4 enclosure you should issue

`sg_ses --dsn=1 --set=ident /dev/sg4`

and, alike, to turn it off

`sg_ses --dsn=1 --clear=ident /dev/sg4`